# Regex replacing specific characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace some case when I put a generic term (here called tampon).

Rules:

1. I want to replace "AM into "AN","EM" into "AN", IM"into"IN","OM"into "ON","UM" into "UN" and "YM" into "IN".
2. I also want to replace them only if a consonant is after them except "M" and "N".
3. I need to replace only the case too when they are alone or at the end of the string.

I've tried some regex but still got some failures into my test (5/18).

Got faillure with "UMUMMUM" the test expects "UMUMMUM" but I've got "UMUMMUN".

Here is my code now :

```
public class Phonom {
    static String[] consonnant={"B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Z",""};
    public static String phonom1(final String tampon){
        if (tampon == null){
            return "";
        }
        if (tampon.isEmpty()){
            return "";
        }


        int pos=tampon.indexOf("EM");
        int pos1=tampon.indexOf("AM");
        int pos2=tampon.indexOf("IM");
        int pos3=tampon.indexOf("OM");
        int pos4=tampon.indexOf("UM");
        int pos5=tampon.indexOf("YM");
        if(pos==tampon.length()-2 ||pos1==tampon.length()-2|pos2==tampon.length()-2
                ||pos3==tampon.length()-2||pos4==tampon.length()-2||pos5==tampon.length()-2){
            String temp=tampon.replaceAll("AM","AN");
            String temp1=temp.replaceAll("EM","AN");
            String temp2=temp1.replaceAll("IM","IN");
            String temp3=temp2.replaceAll("OM","ON");
            String temp4=temp3.replaceAll("UM","UN");
            String result=temp4.replaceAll("YM","IN");
            return result;
        }
        String temp=tampon.replaceAll("AM[^AEIOUMNY]","AN");
        String temp1=temp.replaceAll("EM[^AEIOUMNY]","AN");
        String temp2=temp1.replaceAll("IM[^AEIOUMNY]","IN");
        String temp3=temp2.replaceAll("OM[^AEIOUMNY]","ON");
        String temp4=temp3.replaceAll("UM[^AEIOUMNY]","UN");
        String result=temp4.replaceAll("YM[^AEIOUMNY]","IN");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you expect `UMUMMUM` to stay unchanged, but didn't you also say that you are supposed to replace `UM` if it's at the end of the string?

Comment: Suggestion to improve your code: you should not "handle" your different rules ("AM" to "AN", "EM" to "EN") this way. For example, you can use a HashMap. The hashmap key would be the "search pattern", like "AM"; and the hashmap value is the "replace pattern", like "AN". Add all such "pairs" to the hashmap. Afterwards, you can iterate the map for each "pair". This avoids typing "AM", "AN", and so on ... all the time. Instead you can write generic ... this will make your code shorter; much easier to read, understand, and modify.

Comment: That's right but the test I use(not mine) give me UMUMMUM result with no others rules I've give to you.

Comment: @NatsuMiko Then you have a more fundamental problem than writing your code. If the "external" test does not check the **same** rules that you are supposed to implement; then you can't solve this problem. Either the rules are correct; then the test is wrong; of if the test is "correct", then the set of rules that you are relying on is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see now. **Your** output is unchanged, but it *should* be `UMUMMUN`. The test is expecting `UMUMMUN` and that's not what your output is. Right?

Comment: @RealSkeptic i will disturb my teacher so cause the rules are the ones he gaves to me but also the tests.

Comment: No, no, I am saying that you are reading the test results wrong. I have ran your program myself and it is returning `UMUMMUM`. So you are probably reading the test incorrectly - it is looking for `UMUMMUN` and your program is wrong and returns `UMUMMUM`. Did you test your program yourself before running it through the tester program?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The test class I use compare my result with the program(I rewrite a C program into a Java one and I need same rules). My teacher just said to me I've got a problem with my return(for him I only watch the first caseand not others)

Comment: But you are reading the results wrong. I am asking again: Did you run your program yourself, with a `main` that prints the result, and check what your program returns for different inputs? Because that's usually an essential stage before you try to run with the official test. You would see for yourself what your output is so you would know what your test is saying. I'm not saying the test is wrong. I am saying that you are misinterpreting its results.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Will do that. Sorry for  misinterpreting your words. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this in one line if YM was replaced with YN not IN.

> tampon.replaceAll("(?<=[AEIOUY])(M)(?![AEIOUYMN])", "N");

Because of the YM to IN rule you will need to use appendReplacement and appendTail instead. The below code uses a negative look ahead to ensure possible replacements aren't followed by a vowel, M or N. If the first group is a Y we replace the match with IN. If not we use a back reference to the character in group 1 and follow it with an N.

```
public class Phonom {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([AEIOUY])(M)(?![AEIOUYMN])");

    public static String phonom1(String tampon) {

        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(tampon);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            if ("Y".equals(m.group(1))) {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, "IN");
            } else {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, "\1N");
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```